# Access is denied error for anaconda command prompt for Anaconda 3.2019 version

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda3 2019.3 version on windows 10. A few days ago, I updated the window & ever since that I'm getting this error:

> Access is denied
>
> The system cannot find the file Are.
>
> Could Not Find C:\Users\Who Are You\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-32451.tmp

[image]

I tried running it as administrator but nothing changed, I still got the same error.

[image]

I am unable to activate other environments installed on the anaconda. Instead the base python version runs all the time.

```
activate python36
```

With this error, neither I'm able to access other environments nor I'm able to do any updation to them through their command prompt. And every time I run anaconda I get this error. The base python version is running fine, but it's command prompt also throws this error. However, I'm able to install any package I want on base python even after this error.

What is this error and how can I solve it? I've tried reinstalling anaconda, but I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be really great.

Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I found this helps : https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8510

Apparently you need to change your TMP & TEMP environment variables to another path like E:/temp , etc.